# Como cambiar el alto de simplebar en un componente, no en el estilo raiz en angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

¿cómo puedo cambiar la altura de mi barra de desplazamiento? He visto que `simplebar-scrollbar :: before{ height: 25px}` funciona pero solo en el estilo global y que afectaría a otros componentes, necesito usarlo solo en mi componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto debes utilizar un selector especial en en css o scss de tu componente

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

.css

```
:host /deep/ h3 {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

.scss

```
:host ::ng-deep h3 {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

esto anula la encasulación de estilos para solo elementos del componente, y aplicar estilos para elementos que este contenido en este sin importar sin son generados por scripts